# Checking if a string has a dash-integer at the end of it

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need your help with some regex and string matching. How do I go about checking if my string (represented by var str) has a dash and an integer at the end of it? Consider the following examples:

```
Example 1:

var str = "test101-5"

evaluate the str and check if it end with a dash and an integer { returns true }

Example 2:

var str = "ABC-DEF-GHI-4"

evaluate the str and check if it end with a dash and an integer { returns true }


Example 3:

var str = "test101"

evaluate the str and check if it end with a dash and an integer { returns false }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.test()` with the following regular expression:

```js
var str = "ABC-DEF-GHI-4";
console.log(/-\d$/.test(str)); // true

str = "test101";
console.log(/-\d$/.test(str)); // false
```

The `$` will require the match to occur at the end of the string only.

Comment: Outstanding! Is there anyway to grab the integer's value as well?

Comment: Yes, once you have a match, you can just get the last character and make it a number with `+`: `+str.substr(-1)`. More generally you can grab matches with the `String#match` method: `str.match(/-(\d)$/)[1]`. But be aware that `match` returns `null` when there is no match.

Comment: @BobbyJones you can use RegExp capture groups

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group to get the last digit.

```js
const
  regex = /-(\d)$/,
  tests = [
    'test101-5',
    'ABC-DEF-GHI-4',
    'test101'
  ];
  
tests.forEach(test => {
  const
    // Index 0 will have the full match text, index 1 will contain 
    // the first capture group. When the string doesn't match the 
    // regex, the value is null.
    match = regex.exec(test);
    
  if (match === null) {
    console.log(`The string "${test}" doesn't match the regex.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`The string "${test}" matches the regex, the last digit is ${match[1]}.`);
  }
});
```

The regex does the following:

```
-     // match the dash
(     // Everything between the brackets is a capture group
  \d  // Matches digits only
)
$     // Match the regex at the end of the line.
```

Comment: The `{1}` is unnecessary. `\d` already means "one digit". The surrounding `-` and `$` already require no second digit can be allowed. But even if that would not be the case `{1}` would not change a thing.